# http route url parts to different server

Tags: php, wordpress, go, routes, google-cloud-platform

I'm not sure what the correct verbiage is for this question, but here it goes.

I want to set up two web applications. One is based on golang and the other is apache/php (wordpress)

These applications will be hosted as separate google cloud platform API engines.

I would like these to be published under the same domain, so for example the main golang app URL would be www.mygolangapp.com and the wordpress url would be www.mygolangapp.com/blog

I'm thinking I may need to setup a google VPC network. Could anyone confirm this, and/or provide better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of options depends on which compute system you are using:

- Google App Engine - GAE has build in [request routing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/how-requests-are-routed#routing_via_url) which allows you to have different URLs served by different "modules" or "versions".
- Google Compute Engine - on GCE you can use Cloud HTTP Load Balancing to do [Content-Based Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/content-based-example) to send different paths to different instance groups.
- Google Container Engine - on GKE you can create an [Ingress with fanout](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/), to send different paths to different pods.